# Color rows with \rowcolor and datatool \DTLforeach loop

Tags: tables, datatool, rowcolor

I try to obtain alternate colored rows (just like the table is shown in the figure) using the `datatool` package and the `\rowcolor` command.
I am following the datatool user manual example for striped tables, but it is not enterely clear.
The issue for me is how to color the first row, because the manual does not really deal with that.

It looks like `\rowcolor`, `\DTLifoddrow`, `\DTLiffirstrow` and `\DTLiflastrow` has themselves certain rules which I can't understand fully.

Is there a more compact way to do this? I mean, why it is not possible to call all the \rowcolor statements inside the loop?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
position
first
second
third
fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{rows}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange} % <- redundant? really needed?
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{
    \word%
    \DTLiflastrow{}{\\\DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{gray}}{\rowcolor{orange}}}%
    }
\\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal seems to be to reduce redundancy, I suggest using something like this, or the more flexible variant given below:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
position
first
second
third
fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\colorlet{OddRowColor}{orange}%
\colorlet{EvenRowColor}{gray!20}%

\DTLloaddb{rows}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\rowcolor{OddRowColor}%
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
  \word
  \\ % ending the row, \noalign can thus be used here
  \DTLiflastrow{}{% This is the color for the *next* row, hence the odd/even
                  % shift compared to what datatool just processed
    \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{EvenRowColor}}{\rowcolor{OddRowColor}}%
  }%
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Note regarding `filecontents`: if your LaTeX2e release is from October 2019 or more recent, it has features that render the  `filecontents` package obsolete. In this case, you can replace the part preceding `\documentclass` with the following (see [here](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/10/15/issue30-of-latex2e-news-released/) for details, in particular the [LaTeX2e News Issue 30](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews30.pdf)):

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader,overwrite]{data.csv}
position
first
second
third
fourth
\end{filecontents}
```

Back to our document. If you find the markup too verbose in the `tabular`, you can define a macro like this:

```latex
\newcommand*{\myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable}{%
  \DTLiflastrow{}{% This is the color for the *next* row, hence the odd/even
                  % shift compared to what datatool just processed
    \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{EvenRowColor}}{\rowcolor{OddRowColor}}%
  }%
}
```

Then your tabular can look like:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c}
\rowcolor{OddRowColor}%
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
  \word
  \\ % ending the row, \noalign can thus be used here
  \myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable
}
\end{tabular}
```

It's tempting to make `\myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable` accept the two colors as parameters, but this would miss the first tabular row which also needs its color to be given. So, to get one step further, you would need to define macros before the table that expand to the desired colors, like this:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
position
first
second
third
fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand*{\myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable}{%
  \DTLiflastrow{}{% This is the color for the *next* row, hence the odd/even
                  % shift compared to what datatool just processed
    \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{\myColorForEvenRows}}%
                {\rowcolor{\myColorForOddRows}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\mySetColorsForNextTable}[2]{%
  \def\myColorForOddRows{#1}%
  \def\myColorForEvenRows{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\myApplyColorToFirstRow}{%
  \rowcolor{\myColorForOddRows}%
}

\DTLloaddb{rows}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\mySetColorsForNextTable{orange}{gray!20}%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\myApplyColorToFirstRow
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
  \word
  \\ % ending the row, \noalign can thus be used here
  \myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c}
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
    \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{orange}}{\rowcolor{gray}}%
    \word
    \\
}
\end{tabular}
```

This doesn't work because of the way `\rowcolor` and TeX alignments such as `\halign` (like the `tabular` environment) work. `\rowcolor` uses a TeX primitive called `\noalign`, which can only appear at the beginning of the first line or after a `\cr` or `\crcr` (which is used internally by `tabular` to end a tabular row, when you use `\\`). When looking for `\noalign` or `\omit` (which is special in the same respect as `\noalign` for this discussion), TeX expands tokens and stops at the first non-expandable, non-space token (cf. TeXbook p. 240).

When using `\rowcolor` at the beginning or end of a line, the first non-expandable, non-space token found is `\noalign`, therefore it works fine. But when using something even simpler than the above non-working code:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{c}
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
    \rowcolor{blue}%
    \word
    \\
}
\end{tabular}
```

you get an error like so:

```
./thefile.tex:23: Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...l.23 }
```

This is because `\DTLforeach` is expanded as part of the aforementioned process during which TeX expands tokens looking for `\noalign` or `\omit`, and this stops at a non-expandable, non-space token way before `\rowcolor` got a chance to be expanded and yield its `\noalign`. Indeed, in order to check if its star form is used, `\DTLforeach` starts by calling `\new@ifnextchar`, which contains a `\let` in its expansion, and `\let` is precisely a non-expandable, non-space token. At this point, using `\noalign` before the next `\cr` or `\crcr`,<sup>1</sup> becomes invalid. TeX then processes the start template of the next column (what you can define with `>{...}` when using the `array` package), then the entry contents before getting to the column's end template. While processing the entry contents, TeX expands the `\rowcolor` macro following `\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{`, and this expansion yields the `\noalign` we already mentioned. Unfortunately, it is too late for `\noalign` to be valid here, because of the `\let` obtained from the expansion of `\DTLforeach`. `\noalign` will only be valid to see again after the next `\cr` or `\crcr`.

## Are `\DTLiflastrow` and `\DTLifoddrow` safe?

You may wonder why `\DTLiflastrow` and `\DTLifoddrow` appear to work in our example, where `\DTLforeach*` doesn't. Well... because you've been lucky! Update: we are explaining a [bug present in datatool 2018/12/07 v2.31](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?action=view&key=130); in the meantime, it has been fixed in `datatool` 2019/09/27 v2.32.

Look at this definition:

```latex
 \gdef\DTLiflastrow##1##2{%
   \expandafter\ifnum
    \csname c@DTLrow\romannumeral\dtlforeachlevel\endcsname
    =\csname dtlrows@#2\endcsname\relax
     ##1%
   \else
     ##2%
   \fi}%
```

There was a little bug (or, let's say, undesirable behavior): it works better without the `\relax`. In order to trigger the bug (only present in `datatool` < 2.32), try to use `\rowcolor` in the 〈true〉 clause of \DTLiflastrow, you'll get a “Misplaced `\noalign`” error, just as we explained. So, with “old” `datatool` (e.g., 2018/12/07 v2.31), `\DTLiflastrow` can only contain `\noalign` material in the 〈false〉 clause. You weren't hit by the bug because TeX skips over the `\relax` without seeing it when the `\DTLiflastrow` test is false (i.e., when it is looking for the `\else` token), and you were only using `\noalign` material in the 〈false〉 clause. But the problem is easy to correct, and the fix is now in `datatool` 2019/09/27 v2.32: since `\dtlrows@DBNAME` is a `\countdef` token, it is a 〈number〉 according to TeX's grammar, therefore the `\relax` wasn't needed. If one removes the `\relax` (beware, there are **two places** that do `\gdef\DTLiflastrow` in datatool.sty, one for `\DTLforeach` and one for `\DTLforeach*`), then one can manually append, say, a green line containing `abc` to the tabular, like this:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
position
first
second
third
fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand*{\myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable}{%
  \DTLiflastrow{\rowcolor{green}}{%
    \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{\myColorForEvenRows}}%
                {\rowcolor{\myColorForOddRows}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\mySetColorsForNextTable}[2]{%
  \def\myColorForOddRows{#1}%
  \def\myColorForEvenRows{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\myApplyColorToFirstRow}{%
  \rowcolor{\myColorForOddRows}%
}

\DTLloaddb{rows}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\mySetColorsForNextTable{orange}{gray!20}%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\myApplyColorToFirstRow
\DTLforeach*{rows}{\word=position}{%
  \word
  \\ % ending the row, \noalign can thus be used here
  \myApplyAlternatingColorsForTable
}
abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

`\DTLifoddrow` didn't have this bug (we would have noticed since we used both its 〈true〉 and 〈false〉 clauses), but `\DTLiffirstrow` had it for both `\DTLforeach` and `\DTLforeach*` in `datatool` < 2.32. All this has been fixed in `datatool` 2019/09/27 v2.32. The above example works out of the box with that version.

---

**Footnote**

1. End-of-line primitives for TeX alignments (`\halign` and `\valign`), internally used by `tabular`, `array` and friends.

Comment: Maybe I was no clear. I want no headers. I just would to know  why it is not possible to call all the \rowcolor statements inside the loop.

Comment: This is because `\rowcolor` uses `\noalign` and thus can only be called in specific places, I'll explain that in the answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with detailed explanations and uncovered a bug in `\DTLiflastrow` when using `\noalign` material such as `\rowcolor` in the 〈true〉 clause (`\DTLiffirstrow` has the same bug, maybe also other tests). I've explained how to fix the bug, but of course, it should be reported to the package author (my version of datatool.sty is the last to this date).

Comment: I have submitted a report on [datatool's bug tracker](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi). According to Nicola's site, it may need a few days to appear because of spam filtering measures.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I understand the main ideas, despite my limited knowledge of low level TeX (I'm just a curious end user of LaTeX). Congratulations for finding the bug!

Comment: Yes, it's tricky. To fully understand these issues, you basically need to read the TeXbook up to, and including chapter 22 (“Alignment”). When I first read that book, I thought: “Pfff, these old-style alignments, the code is unreadable [Knuth uses no spacing between the `&`, `#`, etc.; that code is really hard on the eyes], LaTeX tabulars are fine, I probably don't need to read that.” Now I know it is useful. :)

Comment: Good news: I've updated the answer to reflect the fact that the [bug](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?action=view&key=130) has been fixed in `datatool` 2019/09/27 v2.32. :-)

Comment: @frougon Once you've updated your answer, maybe you should remove `RequirePackage{filecontents}`... for your answer it's not necessary and will be obsolete in a couple of months.

Comment: @frougon Or change it directly to `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}`

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. Since not everyone is using the latest and greatest LaTeX kernel, it may be a bit early to do this change now. But I'll add a note to mention the new method.

Comment: @frougon You're welcome...the same package gives the notice for users to update :)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Yes, it's certainly good to transition when possible, but I don't see any reason why current uses of the `filecontents` package should break. Anyway, I've added a note explaining when and how one can use this new feature from the LaTeX kernel.