# colortbl has different behavior when tabular contents are \input

Tags: tables, colortbl, rowcolor

I'm typesetting a complex table with the contents created by an external program.  When I use `\input` I get unexpected behavior from `\rowcolor`. See the MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
Works\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \rowcolor{blue!20}%
  A & B
\end{tabular}

Doesn't work\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  % Uncomment line below to get the unexpected behavior
  %\input{mwe-bit.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

where `mwe-bit.tex` simply contains

```
\rowcolor{blue!20}%
A & B
```

being the same two lines as directly included above.  When I run this, the first part works, but the second generates (when uncommented):

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...
l.1 \rowcolor
             {blue!20}
```

I added the `%` after the `\rowcolor` in an abundance of caution, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm still something of a newbie when it comes to posting here, so apologies for any missteps.

(Update, original post had a pair of `\rowcolor` instructions for each attempt.  I'd been thinking it was something to do with changing an already-specified color, but actually, just having one inside the inputted file is sufficient to generate the error)

Comment: Doesn't rowcolor have to be the very first thing in the first cell in a row? Here something else is being executed as well (the input), thus rowcolor is no longer first. Why are you inputting inside a tabular in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it seems consistent with the answer below.  I'm \input-ing the content because, for various reasons, it's auto-generated by an off-line program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it must be subject to `\rowcolor`, you need to treat the first tabular line out of your `\input` file (or do something else like putting also the tabular preamble in the `\input` file). This is because `\rowcolor` expands to tokens, one of which is `\noalign`, and `\noalign` can only happen at very specific places in a TeX alignment such as tabular. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492400/73317) for a detailed explanation about this (this is also explained below).

The following works:

main.tex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
Works\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \rowcolor{blue!20}%
  A & B
\end{tabular}

Also works\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \rowcolor{green!20}% first line must be colored out of the \input file
  foobar
  \input{mwe-bit.tex}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

mwe-bit.tex:

```latex
\\
\rowcolor{blue!20}%
A & B
```

[image: Screenshot]

In your case, you get the dreaded “Misplaced `\noalign`” error because `\input` executes `\@ifnextchar`, which executes `\let` (at least, this is *one* reason why this error must happen; there might be others quite similar, e.g., from some command other than `\@ifnextchar`). `\let` being a non-expandable, non-space token, TeX stops his expansion of tokens looking for `\noalign` or `\omit` at the beginning of the tabular or after the end of a tabular line (after the `\cr` or `\crcr` command used internally by tabular). Because of this, it doesn't expand `\rowcolor` at this point, and when it eventually does, it is already processing the first tabular entry *contents*, where `\noalign` is invalid. **`\noalign` is only valid during the special expansion step** looking for `\noalign` or `\omit` at the start of a tabular<sup>1</sup> or after a `\cr` or `\crcr`, special step which stops at the first non-expandable, non-space token.

My example works because:

1. The first `\rowcolor` at the very beginning of the tabular gets expanded during the “special step” I just described, and the first non-expandable, non-space token is `\noalign` (from `\rowcolor`'s definition), which allows `\rowcolor` to work as designed.
2. Other `\rowcolor` commands from mwe-bit.tex occur right after `\\`, and if we look at the definition of `\\` in tabular, it is probably not very different from `\crcr` (I guess there is an `\unskip` before, but “before” contents can't cause any problem: what counts is what there is between `\cr` or `\crcr` and `\noalign` material). When performing the “special expansion step” started by `\\`, TeX finds no intervening non-expandable, non-space token before arriving at the `\noalign` from `\rowcolor`; therefore this one can also work as designed (i.e., put the color `\special` material where it belongs).

---

**Footnote**

1. More generally, a TeX alignement such as `\halign` or `\valign`.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful and clearly fixed the problems.  Rather than move the preamble into the auto-generated input file I think I'll move that first rowcolor out of it into the enclosing source file.

Many thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. In the answer I linked to, you can find ideas in order not to duplicate the color information in several places if this is important to you (maybe not that much, since you can probably handle such “unity” at the level of your program that generates the LaTeX code). Anyway, the ideas in question are not rocket science. :-)

Comment: Ha!  Thanks again.