# \noalign caused by multirow and colors

Tags: tables, color, multirow, colortbl, rowcolor

I am trying to create the following table

[image]

However, I keep getting the following error message

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...
l.24       \tableHeaders{Figur}{Antall sirkler}

I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

I tried adding {} around the arguments to make sure `siunitx` columns worked, however even that did not work. To summarize

- How can I fix the white space between the multicolumns? I added `\\[-0.02cm]`, but that feels like the worlds dirtiest trick.
- How can I fix the `\noalign` error?
- Is there a better way to center the `n` at the bottom of the table?

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, dvipsnames*,svgnames, table, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maincolorLight}{HTML}{838fbc}
\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}
\definecolor{maincolorDark}{HTML}{003d80}

\newcommand{\maincolor}{maincolorLight}
\newcommand{\Rowcolor}{\rowcolor{\maincolor}}

\newcommand{\tableHeaders}[2]{%
   \Rowcolor                        & \\[-0.02cm]
   {\Rowcolor \multirow{-2}{*}{#1}} & {\multirow{-2}{*}{#2}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| S | S |}
      \tableHeaders{Figur}{Antall sirkler} 
          1  &  6 \\
          2  & 10 \\
          3  & 14 \\
          4  &    \\
          5  &    \\
         {n} &    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:del-1-oppgave-1.8}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're complicating your own life with `multirow`.

The braces are at the wrong place: no brace can precede `\rowcolor`, which *doesn't* make part of the next cell. The contents of the cell should be braced, because it's in an `S` column.

Be sure to *always* state the number of digits in an `S` column.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, dvipsnames*,svgnames, table, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maincolorLight}{HTML}{838fbc}
\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}
\definecolor{maincolorDark}{HTML}{003d80}

\newcommand{\maincolor}{maincolorLight}
\newcommand{\Rowcolor}{\rowcolor{\maincolor}}
\newcommand{\headerstrut}{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}

\newcommand{\tableHeaders}[2]{\Rowcolor {#1\headerstrut} & {#2} \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| S[table-format=1.0] | S[table-format=2.0] |}
  \tableHeaders{Figur}{Antall sirkler} 
  1    &  6 \\
  2    & 10 \\
  3    & 14 \\
  4    &    \\
  5    &    \\
 {$n$} &    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\cellcolor` instead of `\rowcolor` you get the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, dvipsnames*,svgnames, table, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maincolorLight}{HTML}{838fbc}
\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}
\definecolor{maincolorDark}{HTML}{003d80}

\newcommand{\maincolor}{maincolorLight}
\newcommand{\Rowcolor}{\rowcolor{\maincolor}}

\newcommand{\tableHeaders}[2]{%
   \Rowcolor                        & \\
   {\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{\maincolor}#1}} & {\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{\maincolor}#2}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
      \tableHeaders{Figur}{Antall sirkler}
          1  &  6 \\
          2  & 10 \\
          3  & 14 \\
          4  &    \\
          5  &    \\
         {n} &    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:del-1-oppgave-1.8}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{` before `\Rowcolor` makes TeX insert the alignment entry 〈pre〉-text and stop its search for `\noalign` material, which `\rowcolor` contains. The reason is that `{` is a non-space, non-expandable token (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492948/colortbl-has-different-behavior-when-tabular-contents-are-input/492984#492984) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492400/73317) for more detailed explanations on TeX's behavior at the beginning or end of a tabular row). Removing this additional grouping level solves the problem, because then the `\noalign` used by `\rowcolor` is correctly found while TeX is expanding tokens looking for `\noalign` or `\omit`, *before* it starts to read the alignment entry 〈pre〉-text.

Note: what I call 〈pre〉-text corresponds to `>{...}` material declared in the `tabular` or `array` preamble when using the `array` package.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, dvipsnames*,svgnames, table, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maincolorLight}{HTML}{838fbc}
\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}
\definecolor{maincolorDark}{HTML}{003d80}

\newcommand{\maincolor}{maincolorLight}
\newcommand{\Rowcolor}{\rowcolor{\maincolor}}

\newcommand{\tableHeaders}[2]{%
   \Rowcolor                        & \\[-0.02cm]
   \Rowcolor \multirow{-2}{*}{#1} & {\multirow{-2}{*}{#2}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
      \tableHeaders{Figur}{Antall sirkler}
          1  &  6 \\
          2  & 10 \\
          3  & 14 \\
          4  &    \\
          5  &    \\
         {n} &    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:del-1-oppgave-1.8}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

And if you use [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), it is easy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor}

\definecolor{maincolorLight}{HTML}{838fbc}
\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}
\definecolor{maincolorDark}{HTML}{003d80}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}

% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/18*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/18*5\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\light{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
\def\cals@bgcolor{maincolorLight}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\newcommand{\hstrut}{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}

% R1
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \light\alignC\cell{\vfil Figur\hstrut}
    \cell{\vfil Antall sirkler\hstrut}\light
\erow
\mdseries}
% R2 Body
\brow
    \bb\cell{\vfil $1$}
    \cell{\vfil 6}
\erow

% R3 Body
\brow
    \cell{$2$}
    \cell{$10$}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \cell{$3$}
    \cell{$14$}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \cell{$4$}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \cell{\vfil$5$}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \bb\cell{{\vfil$n$}}
    \cell{}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]